# Notification for modification of a particular Wikidata field

Tags: gratis, notification, wikidata

I want to be notified whenever a particular **property** of a particular Wikidata item **changes**.

For instance, whenever someone changes the "official website" property of item "[Louvre](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q19675)".

There is a Wikidata star/watchlist feature, but it is not applicable to a particular property: Notifications show up whenever someone updates another property (which happens very often).

Requirements:

- Free, ideally open source
- Does not warn about other properties changes
- Does not warn about other items changes
- Preferably ability to define several, for instance property A of item B and property C of item D

Any kind of notification is OK, but in order of preference:

1. In-wiki [watchlist](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:Watchlist) notification
2. In-wiki notification
3. RSS/Atom
4. Email

The first two are probably very difficult to implement, so the last two are perfectly acceptable as well.

Comment: Since you have no answers, I recommend http://www.changedetection.com/  Alas, notification is by email only, and, worse, it won't let you monitor a specific part of a page. It is free, though and I have happilly used it for years.

Comment: If you use FireFox, take alook at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/alertbox/

Comment: Wikipedia has a built in watchlist feature, but, alas, it does not let you monitor only parts of a page :-(  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Watchlist